# Как сделать, чтобы контент прижимaлся вниз при появлении клавиатуры?

Tags: javascript, android, css, ios, content

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал отрицательный margin/padding, высоту 0, ничего не помогает. Т.е. я хочу убрать это свободное место между контентом и клавиатурой.

Comment: Это вопрос по Android?

Comment: Вопрос кроссплатформенный

Comment: ios всегда будет прокручивать экран так, чтобы активный инпут был ровно посередине

Comment: Cheg, а можно пруф, что заказчику сказать?

Comment: @АлександрСавчук к сожалению, пруфа нет, т.к. это лишь мое наблюдение, которое я сам исправить не смог. Возможно, вам поможет вот такой вариант https://stackoverflow.com/a/12485086/8255361

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно попробовать использовать UIScrollView с UITextField внутри, и в зависимости от выбранного textField делать определенный scrollView.contentInset, тогда каждый textField будет ровно над клавиатурой и никаких пустых мест не будет, более того, пользователь сможешь скролить от одного textField к следующему и наоборот.